# Show that $\int_{\gamma} \frac{z^{p-1}}{z^2+1} d{z} = 2\pi i\cos\left(\frac{\pi p}{2}\right)e^{i\pi(p-1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to show that

$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{z^{p-1}}{z^2+1} d{z} = 2\pi i\cos\left(\frac{\pi p}{2}\right)e^{i\pi(p-1)}\,\,,\,\gamma:=\{z\;\;;\;\;|z|=R\}$$

for $0 < p < 2$. This integral computes the path of the contour excluding the branch line along the positive real axis. So I'm really computing $\int_{\gamma}$ part in:

$$\int_{\gamma} = \int_{C_1} + \int_{C_2} + \int_{C_3} + \int_{C_4}$$

where $C_1, C_2, C_3$ and $C_4$ are all pieces of the contour.

I've computed the residues at $z=i$ and $z=-i$ but for some reason my calculations don't check out. I got $$\displaystyle\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}(p-1)}}{2i} - \frac{e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}(p-1)}}{2i}.$$

Comment: What's your curve of integral?

Comment: $\gamma$ is a circle of radius $R$

Comment: Well I solved my problem. I thought that this question would make sense to all of you. Funny how the thoughts in my mind don't translate well in basic English.

Comment: That's why they sell books on communication :-). What is your solution?

Comment: Which radius $R$?

Comment: What are the $C_k$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the contour of integration is as follows

$\hspace{4.5cm}$[image]

The only residues contained in $\gamma$ would be at $i$ and $-i$.
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Res}_{z=i}\left(\frac{z^{p-1}}{z^2+1}\right)
&=\frac{e^{i\pi(p-1)/2}}{2i}\\
&=-e^{i\pi p}\frac{e^{-i\pi p/2}}{2}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Res}_{z=-i}\left(\frac{z^{p-1}}{z^2+1}\right)
&=\frac{e^{i3\pi(p-1)/2}}{-2i}\\
&=-e^{i\pi p}\frac{e^{i\pi p/2}}{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get
$$
\int_\gamma\frac{z^{p-1}}{z^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}z=-2\pi i\,e^{i\pi p}\cos\left(\frac{\pi p}{2}\right)\tag{3}
$$
and $(3)$ should be valid for all $p\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't there be a residue corresponding to the z=0 when p is different from 1?
Hope this helps.